# How can I instantiate a IList<T> of nested IList<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, list

I am trying to create a list of lists but am having trouble instantiating the list.

```
IList<IList<T>> allLists = List<List<T>>();
```

I am getting a compile error with this line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to instantiate a `List` of `IList<T>`, not a `List` of `List<T>`.

The reason is that by implementing `IList<IList<T>>` you are saying "Here is a list of some kind in which you can get or insert anything that implements `IList<T>`". Only objects of type `List<T>` can be inserted into `List<List<T>>`, so it is not allowed.

```
IList<IList<T>> allLists = new List<IList<T>>();
```